# Button created after ajax call not working while event is triggered

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code in html:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead class="inner">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Parent</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="check">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="">test</a></td>
        <td>null</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>
            <button value="3" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="">Lifestyle</a></td>
        <td>null</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <button value="2" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="">Travel</a></td>
        <td>null</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <button value="1" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And I have the following code in the footer:

```
$("#check tr td button").click(function () {
    alert('here');
});
```

But the event does not seems to work. Why is my code not working? The data in table are created after a ajax call. Is it because of ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is registered before the elements exist in the `DOM`, which is why the function is not triggered. The solution is to define the code after your `ajax` or use event delegation as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#check tr td button", function() {
    alert('here');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember at the time you bind event, maybe at that time the object **$("#check tr td button")** is not exist in DOM!

So, the solution is bind event after ajax done.

Put your code into success method of ajax

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'url',
 data: [],
 success: function() {
   // render table code
   // bind event here
   $("#check tr td button").click(function () {
    alert('here');
   });
 }
});
```

OR you can use the event click of document.

```
  $(document).on("click", "#check tr td button", function() {
    // do something you want here 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#check tr td button", function() {
    alert('here');
});
```

**OR**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#check tr td button", function() {
    alert('here');
  });
});
```